# How I can count all elements in 2 or more pages in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The problem is that I can't count all elements on 2 webpages correctly in Selenium.

```
pages = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "page") #getting list of pages
for x in pages:                              #loop through this list
    x.click()                                #click on page number
    prices += driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "final-price") #addition 1pg and 2pg elements 
print(len(prices))
```

Result is wrong: it adds 1pg with 1pg, not 1pg with 2pg.
tried to insert wait - did not help :(
I want to note that page is not reloading, just scroll up and shows new results after clicking on the page 2, it must be using ajax.

Comment: You need to be sure that clicking the page does not reload the whole page if so there could be problems

Comment: Thanks! I want to note that page is not reloading, just scroll up and shows new results

Comment: Post a link to the page. My guess is that you were waiting for the element to be present, etc. but if the element exists before and after the refresh, the wait likely completed before the refresh and that's why you got 1 twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests and bs4 libraries to scrap a website.

For example:

a) I will count how many links are in a site:

b) i will extract href value for each link

```
import requests, bs4

my_request = requests.get('https://www.bellezaculichi.com')
# request one page

my_request.raise_for_status()
# check for error

my_html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_request.text)
# parse site

my_links = my_html.select('a')
#stores all links in list my_links

total_links = len(my_links)
# how many links do i found

print(total_links)
# show how many links


for i in range(total_links):
    my_links[i]["href"]
```

With bs4 you can count any element in a web page.

You can count how many divs, p or a

With bs4 you can count any element by ID in a web page.

With bs4 you can count any element by CLASS in a web page.

With bs4 you can count any element by ATTRIBUTE in a web page.